# How to do when selecting select option toggleClass not force close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I made a button that works to select the number of passengers with the select option. but there was a problem when I selected the number of passengers force close.

How to do when selecting passenger numbers is not force close.

Thanks in advance

I've put his code on > https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/vaqdsmjk/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-passenger").on('click', function(e) {
    $(".passenger-box").toggleClass("s");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-passenger {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.passenger-box.s {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.passenger-box {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-passenger">
  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span id="count">0 click button</span>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="passenger-box">
    <label>Dewasa 12+ Thn</label>
    <select name="adult" id="adult" class="form-control passenger">
      <option selected="selected">1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <label>Anak 2-12 Thn</label>
    <select name="child" id="child" class="form-control passenger">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <label>Bayi
      < 2 Thn</label>
        <select name="infant" id="infant" class="form-control passenger">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a layout design flaw but if you must use this layout check if target is inside the passenger box.

You wouldn't have this problem if you wrapped the actual button elements into their own container

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-passenger").on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.passenger-box').length) {
      $(".passenger-box").toggleClass("s");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-passenger {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.passenger-box.s {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.passenger-box {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-passenger">
  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span id="count">0 click button</span>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="passenger-box">
    <label>Dewasa 12+ Thn</label>
    <select name="adult" id="adult" class="form-control passenger">
      <option selected="selected">1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <label>Anak 2-12 Thn</label>
    <select name="child" id="child" class="form-control passenger">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <label>Bayi
      < 2 Thn</label>
    <select name="infant" id="infant" class="form-control passenger">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can help again .. how to do when the click anywhere then the box closes. I've tried but it does not work https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/vaqdsmjk/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Issues:**

1. You should use `&lt;` or use a text node when you want to insert `<` into a document.  It fixes syntax highlighting, produces more secure and robust code. (Less likely to run into errors).  You should especially do this when you are using `<` (use `&gt;` instead).
2. You can fix it by checking if the target's parent or the target itself is a `select` tag.  Thanks to *charlietfl* for pointing this out.  I just tested this in Internet Explorer and Firefox.  It works in both.  If it isn't a select tag, then you update the visibility of `s`.
3. You could choose to restructure your code.  If you want **only** the button to modify visibility. You can simply stop the button from containing the drop down.  Or you could change the closest to check for `.passenger-box`.

*Comment if you have issues*

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".btn-passenger").on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest("select").length) { //ADDED IF STATEMENT
      $(".passenger-box").toggleClass("s");
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-passenger {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.passenger-box.s {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.passenger-box {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-passenger">
  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span id="count">0 click button</span>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="passenger-box">
    <label>Dewasa 12+ Thn</label>
    <select name="adult" id="adult" class="form-control passenger">
      <option selected="selected">1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <label>Anak 2-12 Thn</label>
    <select name="child" id="child" class="form-control passenger">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <label>Bayi
      &lt; 2 Thn</label>
        <select name="infant" id="infant" class="form-control passenger">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that some browsers will actually allow events on `<option>` which would then be target

Comment: @charlietfl Which browser?  I'd like to try to find a better way of solving this problem, but it'd help if I had a reference point.

Comment: IE won't and I think Safari also...but in Firefox when I choose an option the box hides. So using select as target can have different behaviors depending on browser. Generally best to never rely on click event on `<select>`

Comment: @charlietfl  Thank you very much for your input, updated to accommodate those web browsers.

Comment: FYI same issue with hiding `<option>`. Some will allow it but the first 2 won't (and probably others also), so it's not practical cross browser ... same as relying on option events

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the clickable area smaller, preferably a button to be accessible (clickable div is not accessible to keyboards for example).

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/negzoqca/

Alternatively you could check if user is clicking the `passenger-box` or one of its children and if so not toggle the class. Like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/e0yjb5Lw/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the div.btn-passenger element gets the click event even when you click on the 3 dropdowns as they all are inside the div element.And, I see the click event toggles the visibility on and off. That's why all the dropdown disappear when you try to select an item.

Perhaps, it's better to replace the div.btn-passenger element with a button.

```
<input type="button" value="0 click buttton" class="btn-passenger"/>

<div class="passenger-box">
<label>Dewasa 12+ Thn</label>
<select name="adult" id="adult" class="form-control passenger">
  <option selected="selected">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
<label>Anak 2-12 Thn</label>
<select name="child" id="child" class="form-control passenger">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
<label>Bayi
  < 2 Thn</label>
    <select name="infant" id="infant" class="form-control passenger">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/huxgcj0q/1/